# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, html, flask, encoding

I am writing a python flask program which accepts a file uploaded through html page and search for a string in the file received and return the output. I am able to upload txt file without any error. But when i upload a excel file i receive this error - "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte".

flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from datetime import date



current_date = date.today()
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.files["birthdates"]
        file.save("D:\Projects\Birthdaywish\Test.xlsx")
        with open("Test.xlsx",'r', encoding= "utf-8") as n_file:
            content = n_file.read()
            print(content)
            n_file.close()
        if str(current_date) in content:
            return "<p>sucess</p>"
        else:
            return "<p>Failure</p>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Birthday Greetings</title>
</head>
<body>

<form enctype = "multipart/form-data" action = "/upload" method = "post">
<input type = "file" id = "birthdates" name = "birthdates" />
<p> <input type = "submit" value = "Upload" /> </p>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried to find out what kind of encoding the excel file uses. One solution i found in google was to open the file as notepad and check the encoding there. It showed as "ANSI". So I tried using "Ansi" encoding while opening the file in python which makes the error go away, but string search returns failure which shouldnt happen. Could someone please help me out here?

Comment: `.XLSX` File Extension means a [binary file](https://www.reviversoft.com/en/file-extensions/xlsx) so opening such a file  with the `'r'` flag _must_ lead to unexpected results…